# How to access the any property of imported point-cloud object

Tags: three.js, attributes, geometry, point

I’m trying to access any property of my imported point-cloud model.
When I console.log the model within the function loader.load it works. The first problem is that I don’t know how to get the same result outside the function. I did it only with the last three lines of code but initializing the object with different name.
I used the code for point-cloud models from three.js docs and everything works fine except when I want to change the size of the points. I guess it is due to the different structure of my model (photo attached).
Here’s the code that I use.

```js
import './style.css'
import * as THREE from 'three'

import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { PCDLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/PCDLoader'
import { BufferAttribute, BufferGeometry } from 'three';


let camera, scene, renderer;

            init();
            render();
            

            function init() {

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 30, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 40 );
                camera.position.set( 0, 0, 7 );
                scene.add( camera );

                const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
                controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // use if there is no animation loop
                controls.minDistance = 0.5;
                controls.maxDistance = 10;

                //scene.add( new THREE.AxesHelper( 1 ) );

                const loader = new PCDLoader();
                loader.load( 'pointcloud.pcd', function ( points ) {

                    points.geometry.center();
                    points.geometry.rotateY( Math.PI );
                    points.geometry.rotateX( Math.PI );
                    points.geometry.rotateZ( Math.PI );
                    scene.add( points );
                    console.log(points)

                    render();
                } );

                    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );

                window.addEventListener( 'keypress', keyboard );
                }

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }
            
            function keyboard( ev ) {

                const points = scene.getObjectByProperty( 'pointcloud.pcd' );

                switch ( ev.key || String.fromCharCode( ev.keyCode || ev.charCode ) ) {

                    case '+':
                        points.material.size *= 1.2;
                        break;

                    case '-':
                        points.material.size /= 1.2;
                        break;

                }

                render();
            }

            function render() {

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

            // I used this to acces the object
            const points2 = scene.getObjectByProperty( 'points' );
            console.log(points2)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE5s8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

change `let camera, scene, renderer;` to `let camera, scene, renderer, points`
to make 'points' global.

Answer (score -1):

because the 'points' object only live inside the function, try create a variable outside the loader.load function, then assign the 'points' object to the new variable before render(); now you can access the 'points' from outside this function

Comment: Answer needs some code